# not a single group group by function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g

I am getting not a single group group function on running the below query, what should I do to run this?:

```
SELECT COUNT(wtt1.wrt_ip_num),
       wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd,
       wbm.wbm_room_num,
       wbm.wbm_bed_num,
       TRUNC(wtt1.wrt_in_dt),
       wtt1.wrt_out_dt
  FROM w_transfer_txn wtt1, w_ward_master_base wmb, w_bed_master_base wbm
 WHERE wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd = wmb.wwm_ward_cd
   AND wmb.wwm_ward_locn = 'TMH'
   AND wbm.wbm_bed_num = wtt1.wrt_from_bed_num
   AND wbm.wbm_room_num = wtt1.wrt_from_room_num
   AND wbm.wbm_ward_cd = wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd
   AND (wtt1.wrt_ip_num, wtt1.wrt_sl_num) IN
       (SELECT wtt.wrt_ip_num, MAX(wtt.wrt_sl_num) wrt_sl_num
          FROM w_transfer_txn wtt
         WHERE /*wtt.wrt_ip_num='IP/20/034619' AND*/
               TRUNC(wtt.wrt_in_dt) < TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020', 'DD-MON-`YYYY')
          AND (wtt.wrt_out_dt IS NULL OR (wtt.wrt_out_dt) >= TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
         GROUP BY TRUNC(wtt.wrt_in_dt), wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd, wtt.wrt_ip_num)
 ORDER BY TRUNC(wtt1.wrt_in_dt) DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There some issues and needed rearrangements within the query such as

- Fix your query so as to have explicit `JOIN` syntax between tables
  instead of comma-seperated old `JOIN` syntax in order easily to
  manipulate it.
- All non-aggregated columns should be listed next to `GROUP BY` Clause.

  ```
     GROUP BY wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd, wbm.wbm_room_num, wbm.wbm_bed_num,
              TRUNC(wtt1.wrt_in_dt), wtt1.wrt_out_dt
  ```

  for the outer query. Basically your error is due to this matter. There's only one non-aggregated column(`wtt.wrt_ip_num`) within the subquery. So, using`GROUP BY wtt.wrt_ip_num` is enough.
- `TRUNC(wtt1.wrt_in_dt)` column might be aliased such as `trc_in_dt`, and be used within `ORDER BY` clause with that alias(`ORDER BY trc_in_dt DESC`). Btw, using alias(`wrt_sl_num`) for `MAX(wtt.wrt_sl_num)` within the subquery is redundant.
- There's a backtick within the first date conversion before year
  portion, that's a typo, and should be fixed. Btw,
  `TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` date conversion might be
  replaced with date literal such as `date'2020-09-29'` to make it
  brief.

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(wtt1.wrt_ip_num),
         wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd,
         wbm.wbm_room_num,
         wbm.wbm_bed_num,
         TRUNC(wtt1.wrt_in_dt) AS trc_in_dt,
         wtt1.wrt_out_dt
    FROM w_transfer_txn wtt1
    JOIN w_ward_master_base wmb
      ON wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd = wmb.wwm_ward_cd
    JOIN w_bed_master_base wbm
     AND wbm.wbm_bed_num = wtt1.wrt_from_bed_num
     AND wbm.wbm_room_num = wtt1.wrt_from_room_num
     AND wbm.wbm_ward_cd = wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd   
   WHERE wmb.wwm_ward_locn = 'TMH'
     AND (wtt1.wrt_ip_num, wtt1.wrt_sl_num) IN
         (SELECT wtt.wrt_ip_num, MAX(wtt.wrt_sl_num)-- wrt_sl_num
            FROM w_transfer_txn wtt
           WHERE TRUNC(wtt.wrt_in_dt) < date'2020-09-29'
             AND (wtt.wrt_out_dt IS NULL OR wtt.wrt_out_dt >= date'2020-09-29')
           GROUP BY wtt.wrt_ip_num)
   GROUP BY wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd, wbm.wbm_room_num, wbm.wbm_bed_num, 
            TRUNC(wtt1.wrt_in_dt), wtt1.wrt_out_dt         
   ORDER BY trc_in_dt DESC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There is "group by" part is missing for the parent query

just add this before the "Order by trunc(wtt1.wrt_in_dt) desc" line

```
group by
   wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd,
   wbm.wbm_room_num,
   wbm.wbm_bed_num,
   trunc(wtt1.wrt_in_dt),
   wtt1.wrt_out_dt
```

This should be enough to get rid of "missing group expression" error

Comment: the error is gone but it is going into an infinite loop . Also should there be 2 group by's in a query

Comment: @sandeeppradhan it is hard to say from remote why does it take so long the query to execute. I think the inner query is can be quite optimized. Try this ((Select wtt.wrt_ip_num, max(wtt.wrt_sl_num) wrt_sl_num
          FROM W_TRANSFER_TXN wtt
         where /*wtt.wrt_ip_num='IP/20/034619' and*/
               trunc(wtt.wrt_in_dt) < TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020', 'DD-MON-`YYYY')
           and (wtt.wrt_out_dt is null or wtt.wrt_out_dt >= TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
         group by wtt.wrt_ip_num))

Comment: the "group by" part is required when there are aggregate (aka group) functions involved. All other columns has to be specified within GROUP BY clause. In case of group functions and additional cols for every "select" word there has to be a "group by" clause. 
For example SELECT MAX(col1), col2, col3 .... GROUP BY col2, col3